# How to genrate a blurhash string of a image in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the package **[react-native-blurhash](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-blurhash) **but the problem with that package it is making app very very slow on a real device and on an android emulator it just stops working this all happens if I try to encode the image and try to generate a blurhash string to display a blur placeholder to my image

So is there any other fast way to to genrate a blurhash string of a image in react native? reducing image size do not helps me my images are in 100kbs my images are cloudinary uri

`const blurhash = await Blurhash.encode(image, 4, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try this package in react native, but for now in my case i am doing encoding on backend side ( nodejs , with npm package blurhash ).

Also note that:

- you shouldn't encode big images anyways. It doesn't make sense, as details are lost. Compress and scale it down first.

source - https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/h9iaep/react_native_blurhash_make_your_images_load/